# Add animation to jquery isotopes filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Im trying to understand how isotope works. Currently finished with the filtering functions but how exactly do I animate the items? I read the manual and used the jquery engine to power the animations but to be honest im not sure where to start.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7t8mgont/9/

```
var t = e("#filters");
t.imagesLoaded(function() {
    t.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".people-card",
        filter: "*",
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: "jquery"
    })
});
```

the above is what I tried. Im utterly confused about how im going to achieve this. Just a standard fading / moving.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/macsupport/dkrdkbek/)

You left out the CSS for v1.5 (v2 does not need this for animation). In your case the css is:

```
 /**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.people-card {
  z-index: 2;
 }

.isotope-hidden.people-card {
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.people-cards-container,
.people-cards-container .people-card {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.people-cards-container {
 -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -ms-transition-property: height, width;
   -o-transition-property: height, width;
      transition-property: height, width;
}

.people-cards-container .people-card {
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
   -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
      transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}
```